# What do I need to setup a chainlink node on the Avalanche Fuji testnet?

Tags: chainlink, avalanche

I'm trying run a Chainlink node (from source) on the Avalanche Fuji testnet, it seems to start up okay but I'm getting a server error for generating the account addresses.

The error above the Account Addresses in the Key Management menu just states "Server error" and doesn't show any addresses.

It also seems that the node tries to use the Kovan address even though I've changed the ETH URL and chain ID to Avalanche Fuji. The error being "Error: while creating transaction: cannot send transaction on chain ID 43113; eth key with address 0x... is pegged to chain ID 42: task run failed"

I've tried disabling the chain in the Operator dashboard but the error persists.

[Node configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf7de.png)

[Attempting to run a job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJYhx.png)

Below is my .env file for the node. I'm running the node and the postgres server on the same device. This setup (with different environment variables) has worked previously for me on the Kovan testnet.

```
ETH_URL=wss://avalanche--fuji--rpc.datahub.figment.io/apikey/API_KEY/ext/bc/C/ws
FEATURE_EXTERNAL_INITIATORS=true
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=43113
MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS=2
LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=0x0b9d5D9136855f6FEc3c0993feE6E9CE8a297846
CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0
SECURE_COOKIES=false
ALLOW_ORIGINS=*
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@localhost:5432/elvis?sslmode=disable
DATABASE_TIMEOUT=0
FEATURE_FLUX_MONITOR=true
MINIMUM_CONTRACT_PAYMENT_LINK_JUELS=100000000000000000
CHAINLINK_DEV=true
```

Comment: Can you please add in the text the error you're getting as opposed to the image? Others won't be able to search their error. Please copy paste the error and edit the question here.

Comment: I've added the errors in the text

Comment: Hmm... You might need to connect a new database. It looks like its mad you created a key on kovan first